# mvc client side validation broken now that im doing an ajax jquery .post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Hi I am using some ajax with jquery to perform a post of a form.

Heres my jquery:

```
 $("#submit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post("Account/LogOn",
                    $(this.form).serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        if (data.redirect) {
                            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                            window.location.href = data.redirect;
                        }
                        else {
                            // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
                            $("#error").replaceWith(data.error);
                        }
                    },
                    'json'
            );
            return false;
        });
```

This works as expected, however the in built MVC validation no longer works?
(the error messages dont show username required/password required if they are omitted and the form is submitted.).

Any Ideas why clientside validation no longer works?

thanks

Comment: My first guess is the HTML you are replacing is replaced with invalid markup. Causing existing JavaScript validation not to work.  I would need to see more of what the AJAX request is returning.

Comment: the replacing works fine, it shows a string "The user name or password provided is incorrect." if the username/pass combination does not exist. Im asking why client side validation doesn't work anymore - its the basic login form that comes with an mvc project btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the client side validation is triggered by form posts and you are no longer posting the form, you are performing a jQuery post which essentially circumvents the validation triggers.  You have to manually trigger the validation in your javascript and than check if the client-side validation found any errors, and if it did not than you can proceed with the ajax post.

Edit:   [Here's the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) for how to do that.  The code will look similar to this....

```
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this.form).validate();
            if($(this.form).valid())
{
            $.post("Account/LogOn",
                    $(this.form).serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        if (data.redirect) {
                            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                            window.location.href = data.redirect;
                        }
                        else {
                            // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
                            $("#error").replaceWith(data.error);
                        }
                    },
                    'json'
            );
            return false;
}
        });
```

Comment: Depends on the which validation framework you are using.  The jquery validation will probably be like this ... http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid.  Edited my answer for clarification.